# An inverted pyramid

Tags: graphics, matrix, algorithm, expression-construction

I want to draw a pyramid approximately like this

```
MatrixPlot[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, 40],
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Mesh -> All,
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

"Approximately" because I don't want the disturbing black stripes to the left and right of the pyramid diagonals.

I have tried many things but found nothing which I would dare to show here.

How could a functional solution  (preferably not relying on `CellularAutomaton`) look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you were to allow `CellularAutomaton` I think the simplest change is to drop every other row and column:

```
MatrixPlot[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, 80][[;; ;; 2, ;; ;; 2]],
 ImageSize -> 400, Mesh -> All, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

There is however a discontinuity in the center compared to your original.

I'll start working on other options.

---

From your earlier question seeking a functional solution I believe you wish to avoid `Table`, `Array`, etc., which the other existing answers use.  One may be able to "cheat" to your satisfaction with `SparseArray`, e.g.:

```
(* ybeltukov's conditional *)
n = 41;
SparseArray[
{i_, j_} /; 
    Abs[2 j - 1 - n] < i && Xor[Mod[Abs[2 j - 2 - n] - i, 3] == 0, 2 j > n + 1] ->
 1, {n, n}] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

If this is not to your liking, and since you wish to avoid `CellularAutomaton`, perhaps this rather contrived yet hopefully functional approach, also using dropping rows:

```
k = Riffle[#, {0, 0, 0}] & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]
m = PadRight[{{}}, {41, 41}, Reverse @ k];
m2 = LowerTriangularize[#][[All, ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {m, 1 - m};
Join[Reverse[#2, {2}], #, 2] & @@ m2 // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Comment: You are here one of the few species without full employment. Brilliant.

Comment: @eldo I have no idea what that means, but thanks for "brilliant."

Comment: I wanted to say: "Most questions are too easy for you, so that your brains only find part-time jobs." And this without any irony. Sorry for having been vague :)

Comment: @eldo lol -- as you can see my brain isn't all that great or I would have understood. :^)

Comment: @eldo I don't know if I have the "functional" thing figured out but I tried.  Would you let me know if my last method is of the nature that you want?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I also rewrite my code to be more "functional". However, the idea doesn't change.

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution with `And`, `Xor` and `Mod`:

```
n = 41;
Table[If[Abs[2 j - 1 - n] < i && 
   Xor[Mod[Abs[2 j - 2 - n] - i, 3] == 0, 2 j > n + 1], 1, 0], 
   {i, n}, {j, n}] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

The same for `n = 333`:

[image]

---

To be more functional-style:

```
j = ConstantArray[Range@n, n];
i = Transpose@j;
UnitStep[i - 1 - Abs[2 j - 1 - n]] (1 + 
  (1 - 2 Unitize@Mod[Abs[2 j - 2 - n] - i, 3]) Sign[n + 2 - 2 j]) // ArrayPlot
(* the same result *)
```

Comment: Oh that last one is nice!  (I already voted so I can't +1 again.)

Answer (score 7):

The closest I get is this

```
MatrixPlot@
 Table[Boole@((Divisible[Abs[k - n], 3] || 
       k >= 22) && (Divisible[Abs[-22 + k + n], 3] \[Implies] 
       k < 22) && n > 2 Abs[-22 + k]), {n, 41}, {k, 41}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You can  (1) use `{{0, 80, 2}, {-40, 40, 2}}`  as the third argument of `CellularAutomaton` (instead of `40`) or (2) use `Downsample` on the output of  `CellularAutomation`:

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, {{0, 80, 2}, {-40, 40, 2}}], 
 Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
ArrayPlot[Downsample[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, 80], {2, 2}], 
 Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
```

to get

[image]

Using different parameters in the second iterator in `CellularAutomaton` and in the second argument of `Downsample`

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, {{0, 80, 2}, {-40, 40}}], 
 Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] (* or *)
ArrayPlot[Downsample[CellularAutomaton[57, {{1}, 0}, 80], {2, 1}], 
 Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
```

we get

[image]